# how do i search 1 sheet for certain criteria then copy adjacent cell to sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

how do i search sheet1 column 1 until an empty cell is found or it finds a certain criteria then copy adjacent cell to sheet 2 column 2 cell b16 and then loop I also need this to populate sheet 2 with as many matching criteria as there is in sheet 1

Comment: Please share sample data and your desired result. It sounds like the `Find()` method of the `Range` object would be of use here, but it's tough to say. Have you written any code yet where you might be stuck at a particular point in that development of this?

Comment: here is what I have so far, this returns the values to same sheet different column which is ok I can get them from here to sheet 2 but my if statement is not working. once the if condition is met it stops looking and just fills in all content...Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


Dim x As String
x = "a"

Dim i As Integer
i = 9

Range("A9").Select

Do While i < 109

    If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
    
        Cells(i, 24).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
    
    Else
    
        Cells(i, 24).Value = 20
    
    End If
    
    
    i = i + 1
    
Loop


End Sub